# IIS Web Server, not getting response using SoapUI/Postman

Tags: node.js, iis, soapui, windows-server-2008-r2, postman

I just installed some nodejs restful app in IIS (Windows server 2008 R2), and seems to be ok. I can access all the get methods using any browser, even from other computers... all these when using the IP address, however, when specifying the URL for that website (example.dev.company), I can only access localy....
My concerns is that when using POSTMAN or SOAPUI to test these methods (even internally), it just waits, and waits till timeout. Any suggestions on what is going on here? I need some other QA members to test these get and post methods using either POSTMAN or SOAPUI...maybe some permissions in IIS, firewall?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please see if this helps - Edit  hosts file to map ip and its domain name.

Comment: @Rao can't see any link in your comment